# How do I downgrade to an old version of compass using gem install?

Tags: rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I've been using compass from http://compass-style.org/ to manage my sites css for a long time. I just installed the newest version and I get a rather unpleasant error, that has as a side effect corrupted all my css files. How do I downgrade to an older version of this?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
sudo gem install compass --version versionnumber
```

Comment: gem install compass --version VERSION

Comment: @Green `gem uninstall compass` (then remove all versions), then run `gem install compass --version VERSION`.

Comment: I had to both uninstall compass and uninstall sass. It turned out that I had two versions of Sass installed, one that was too new.

Answer (score 86):

I just had a similar situation and there is something else missing from @corroded answer. Since @Matt Lynn is downgrading, he needs to uninstall the existing version of compass.

```
$ sudo gem uninstall compass

$ sudo gem install compass --version versionnumber
```

Otherwise you will end up with two different versions of compass.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to automate it in a script (I had the same problem after a `gem update`), just do the following:

1. Install your favored version (if you don't have already)

   `gem install compass -v 1.2.3`
2. Uninstall newer versions

   `gem uninstall compass -v '>1.2.3' --force`

Answer (score 1):

A Gem update doesn't '*update*' the gem, but it installs a newer version of it.

So you to uninstall the newer version and leave behind the older.

Eg, for me, I wanted to revert back to an older version of `selenium-webdriver`, this is what I did:

```
- gem uninstall selenium-webdriver
```

This gave me an option to select gem to uninstall, with the following options:

```
    1. selenium-webdriver-3.4.3
    2. selenium-webdriver-3.8.0
    3. All versions
```

I entered 2 and the latest version was unistalled, leaving my system with the desired older version.

To install a particular version that doesn't exist in your system, just select 3 to uninstall all versions and install the specific version with:

`gem install selenium-webdriver -v 3.5.3`

Replace `selenium-webdriver` with your gem name and `3.5.3` with the version you want.

Hope this helps somebody!